# (C++) read an arbirtrary file as binary and output the data as a separate text file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to take an arbitrary file and read it as raw binary and then output the data as a separate text file. No assumptions whatsoever can made about the input file as to formatting or encoding. What I've done is (very) roughly:

```
char *pDataBlock = new char[nLength];
 ifstream InputFile("MyInputFile.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
 ofstream OutputFile("MyOutputFile.txt"); 
 while (InputFile)
 { 
  InputFile.read(pDataBlock, nLength);
  OutputFile.write(pDataBlock, nLength);
 }
```

CURRENT PROBLEM:
This code opens MyInputFile.txt in binary mode, but reads one character (byte!) at a time into a C-string called pDataBlock. This C-string is then written to MyOutputFile.txt one byte at a time.

BAD SOLUTION:
The solution that I have now is to insert the following steps to the above code: (1) read a single character of the InputFile, (2) cast this character into an integer, (3) convert the integer to a binary string, (4) output this binary string to OutputFile in append mode, (5) read the next character until EOF.

The problem seems to be that every read/write command I've found associated with fstream involves taking one byte at a time and doesn't allow for bit level manipulations.

Comment: What are you trying to do? create a copy of a file?

Comment: I don't get the whole point of the question. So you just want to copy the contents of one file into another?

Comment: -1 forgot to state purpose and forgot to pose question, + description of what already tried is confusing and with incorrect assertions

Comment: So you would read, say, 0xad (1 byte) and you want to output '0xad' (4 bytes)?  Or perhaps you want to discard characters that cannot be printed (outside of 0x20-0x7f)?  You need to describe what you want better.

Comment: Why do you need bit level manipulations in a file reading function?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, streams cannot operator at lower granularity than one byte. The solution you have right now is not that bad. You can improve it by reading more than one byte at a time, but there's no way to read one bit at a time from a file stream.